# YouTube API search videos by topic id: showing implausibly few results

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

For my project, I want to get a list of youtube videos for different topic ids. However, searching via search: list returns a measly 343 video ids for the biggest topic on youtube (lifestyle) for the year 2020.
I am restricting it to relevanceLanguage = 'en', but this sample just seems too small. Is my request wrong? Or are most videos on YouTube not categorised and that's why search doesn't return it?

```
matches = []

next_page_token = None 
while True:
    request = youtube.search().list(
        maxResults = 50, 
        part = "snippet",
        order= "date",
        topicId = '/m/019_rr',
        publishedAfter = '2020-01-01T00:00:00Z',
        publishedBefore = '2021-01-01T00:00:00Z',
        regionCode="US",
        relevanceLanguage="en",
        type="video",
        pageToken = next_page_token
        )

    response = request.execute()

    for item in response["items"]:
        matches.append(item)

    next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')
    if not next_page_token:
        break
```

Comment: Can you share the total results (number) the API shows and the amount of items you get at the end?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but the topicId parameter accesses the Freebase API, which has been [shut down](https://developers.google.com/freebase) and can only access the last data dump, whenever that was. I wouldn't trust those results.

Comment: thanks – how do you know topicId param accesses this? On the [reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) under "topicId" it says 

> "Important: Due to the deprecation of Freebase and the Freebase API, the topicId parameter started working differently as of February 27, 2017. At that time, YouTube started supporting a small set of curated topic IDs, and you can only use that smaller set of IDs as values for this parameter. –– See topic IDs supported as of February 15, 2017"

I'm using the topicIds as suggested there – why should that not work?

Comment: Well, the "working differently" implies switching from the Freebase API to the last data dump using a small set of topic IDs. Since Freebase shut down in 2016, I'm saying I wouldn't trust those results to be current.

Comment: Thanks – in my example above my query is for recent videos (in 2020), so well after the freebase shut down. is there an alternative explanation? I wish there was somebody to contact about this...